# if Query doesnt not return any data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi i am using the code below to display buttons.

If the Query result is "0" visibility true  WORKING

If query found no data in the data base visibility false. NOT WORKING

```
  string insertSql = "SELECT Status from User_friend WHERE (ProfileId1 =
               @FriendProfileId) AND (ProfileId = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile
                 WHERE UserId = @UserId))";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {


            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendProfileId", 
                           Request.QueryString["ProfileId"]);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
            if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == null)
            {
                friendRequestSent.Visible = false;
                addFriend.Visible = true;

            }
             else if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "0")
            {
                friendRequestSent.Visible = true;
                addFriend.Visible = false;

            }
        }
```

Comment: You get `NullReferenceException`, right?

Comment: You're calling `ExecuteScalar` twice. Store the value once, then run your logic against that.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks. I am new to ASP.NET and dont really understand how to store the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteScalar will have the value `DBNull.Value` for a NULL value. You should also consider to execute the query one, save the result in an object variable, and then use it twice.

```
object result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == DBNull.Value)
{
    friendRequestSent.Visible = false;
    addFriend.Visible = true;
}
else if (Convert.ToString(result) == "0")
{
    friendRequestSent.Visible = true;
    addFriend.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, now i am getting an error for   else if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "0")
                {
                    friendRequestSent.Visible = true;
                    addFriend.Visible = false;
                    
                }

Comment: I edited my response to include the suggestion to execute the query once.

Answer (score 0):

Fist I want to know what `null` meant there. Shouldn't it be `Null`?

```
 if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "Null")
```

Or, if it mean it doesn't exist, you can leave that empty:

```
 if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "")
```

Comment: null means the row does not exist in the database